# LEGO family identification

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

I found this little guy here, I remember I already had it in my childhood (~30 years ago).

[image]

Could somebody tell me what LEGO family it is?

The grid size is 2x2 LEGO studs, it just fits right onto one Duplo stud.
On the inside I see the LEGO logo and the following indication "4 01".

Comment: The most common term for the "cams" you refer to is **studs**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be [4224c01: Basic Figure Finger Puppet Female (bfp001)](https://brickset.com/minifigs/4224c01/basic-figure-finger-puppet-female-(bfp001))

[image]

It appeared in two sets:
[1050-1 Basic Pack](https://brickset.com/sets/1050-1/Basic-Pack) (1986) and [1089-1 Lego Basic Figures](https://brickset.com/sets/1089-1/Lego-Basic-Figures) (1985)

Edit (thanks to [@Mark](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/7591/mark) comment):
While Brickset list only 2 sets with this figurine, [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=4224c01&in=S) lists 25.

Comment: BrickLink lists 28 sets:https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=4224c01&in=S

Comment: @Mark Nicely found, I edited my answer.